# Matplotlib error "cannot import name pyplot" on Ubuntu

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I am trying to run this code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('games.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/home/megha/matplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name pyplot
```

I googled a solution for this but I am only getting that the matplotlib version needs to be upgraded. I tried that too, and its still showing the same error.
I have also tried
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` but I have python 2.7 version, so that didnt work either.

Comment: How did you install `matplotlib`?  `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`?

Comment: @NickHale obviously not, if it comes from `/home/megha/matplotlib.py`

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to give your script the name of a module/package you are looking to import. Change the file name `matplotlib.py` to something else that you are not importing.

Comment: @NickHale I used sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib and also sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib

Comment: @Abdou, whoa, didn't see that!

Comment: @Abdou I changed the name and it worked! Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

Use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` instead.